# RANSAC using SIFT in Computer Vision

Tags: matlab, sift, vision, matlab-cvst, ransac

Currently, I am doing a computer vision project. I used SIFT Matlab program using this: http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/sift.html  codes. However, it gives me two matrices, one is matches and another is distances. I don't know how to convert these information to pixel values because in the next step I have to use RANSAC for getting the best matches. Would somebody please help me?

Comment: For a question on Stack Overflow it is expected that you provide a clear description of what you want to achieve, describe your own attempts to answer the question, and state exactly where you got stuck. Moreover, most of the time it increases the chances for a good answer if you include a *small* piece of (non-) working code (and possibly data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have "matches", i.e. tentative correspondences, which means "feature with index I1 possibly corresponds to feature with index I2". So go the the list of the detected SIFT features and take coordinates of the I1 feature in image 1 and I2 in image 2.

Answer (score 0):

The Computer Vision System Toolbox for MATLAB has various feature detectors and extractors, a function called [matchFeatures](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/matchfeatures.html) to match the descriptors, and a function [estimateGeometricTransform](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/estimategeometrictransform.html) that uses RANSAC to do exactly what you need.

Please check out the following examples: [Find Image Rotation and Scale Using Automated Feature Matching](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/find-image-rotation-and-scale-using-automated-feature-matching.html) and [Detect Objects in a Cluttered Scene Using Point Feature Matching](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/detect-objects-in-a-cluttered-scene-using-point-feature-matching.html)